# Docker Nginx reverse proxy http requests itself times out with getimagesize function

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have setup docker containers with a nginx reverse proxy server and each one website is another container including nginx and php-fpm.

One of my sites uses the php function **getimagesize()**. This function gets as parameter a url of the site itself. But as i read here https://serverfault.com/a/581005

> Even though the image file in question was located on the site itself, the parameter to getimagesize was an HTTP URL. Because of a weird firewall configuration, the server was unable to contact itself via HTTP, so request hang and for reasons unknown, php-fpm stopped serving requests all together.
>
> Finally nginx lost patience logged a timeout error.
>
> After allowing the server to make HTTP requests to itself, the timeout errors went away.

Is there a way to make it possible to request to itself, having a setup like mine ?

Comment: Did you expose ports in your containers?

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure the image isn't served through PHP. fpm has only so many workers, and if they are all busy executing the script that tries to fetch images it will deadlock.

Comment: And you must validate the URL before calling getimagesize. Otherwise a malicious actor could just send the URL to the script itself to induce a deadlock.

Comment: Of course i have exposed ports.

@Peter what do you mean with "the image isn't served through PHP" ? I  have joomla files installed in this container, so the files are served through php ... i suppose!

Comment: If the file is served directly by nginx, without involving PHP, you're good (assuming you validate the URL). Otherwise you will run into a deadlock sooner or later. Consider an extreme scenario where there's only one PHP worker. When you call your script it's going to wait for the image, but the image can't be served because there are no free workers. The same thing can (and will!) happen with multiple workers; it just takes more concurrent requests.

Comment: @Peter thank you for make it clear to me. I am afraid i am not sure how i can achieve that. The nginx proxy has a configuration like the following
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QJsxmGj2)

I think that the php files are served through the proxy and the other files are served through nginx...